# Is it possible, and if so how, to "link" two MySQL database columns together inside two different tables?

Tags: mysql

I have one database that has a bunch of tables in it. 8 of these tables have field named 'status' which gives the effective status notification of the data within that row.

I have another table which is acting like an index to the earlier mentioned 8, and this also has a matching "status" col. Currently if the status col changes in one of the 8 data collection tables, I need to make the php also update the relevant index tables status col to match. It would be much nicer and less error prone to coding oversight, if I had a way inside MySQL to link the index tables 'status' field to the matching 'status' field in which ever of the eight tables the core data resides in. It'll always only be one of the eight, depending on the form type selected. Is such a thing possible?

Data added as per request. First is a sample of what I call the "index" table. Any data placed into one of the other 8 mentioned tabled, will also have an entry into this table.

```
id  appNo   applicationKey  applicationName             uID     status
1   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Data Acquisition
2   2       AIGs1PIA        A.I.G stage 1 Process App   1       Data Acquisition
3   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Declined
4   2       AIGs1PIA        A.I.G stage 1 Process App   1       Data Acquisition
5   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Data Acquisition
6   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Pending Review
7   8       VisFelAp        Visiting Fellowship App     1       Data Acquisition
8   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Data Acquisition
9   8       VisFelAp        Visiting Fellowship App     1       Accepted
```

The id is auto incremental. appNo and applicationKey are used to identify what type of App is being entered. applicationName is obvious, uID is the id of the user who entered the application - myself in all these cases so they're all "1" right now. The last col, 'status' is what I am wanting to be "linked" to the relevant matching column in whichever other table the data resides within. This is indicated by the applicationKey - for example the data for the first entry here will be stored within the table named 'app_AIGs2GRA' whereas the data for the last (id 9) entry will reside within the table 'app_VisFelApp'.

All of the data tables start the same way, like this:

```
appID   uID     uaID    status
1       1       2       Data Acquisition
2       1       4       Data Acquisition
```

This sample is taken from the app_AIGs1PIA table, you'll see how the uaID number matches the id number over in the index table. The 'status' column data here, likewise in the other data tables, is what I need "linked" to the relevant 'status' column within the index table. So if it changes here, to become this:

```
appID   uID     uaID    status
1       1       2       Data Acquisition
2       1       4       Pending Review
```

The index table would then become:

```
id  appNo   applicationKey  applicationName             uID     status
1   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Data Acquisition
2   2       AIGs1PIA        A.I.G stage 1 Process App   1       Data Acquisition
3   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Declined
4   2       AIGs1PIA        A.I.G stage 1 Process App   1       Pending Review
5   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Data Acquisition
6   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Pending Review
7   8       VisFelAp        Visiting Fellowship App     1       Data Acquisition
8   3       AIGs2GRA        A.I.G stage 2 Grant App     1       Data Acquisition
9   8       VisFelAp        Visiting Fellowship App     1       Accepted
```

Note how entry number 4 has also changed?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: you could accomplish this with triggers on each of the 8 tables

Comment: Ok, how would I achieve this?

Comment: specifically, an after update trigger on each table, that then updates the index table with the new status.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Alright, so how would I create one of these triggers - which look exactly like the idea I was looking for, but the link was not very useful in how to implement this on a case by case situation, when a new entry is placed into the index and relevant data table. Obviously I need this to set up automatically each time.

Comment: I also cannot seem to find any reference to this feature, inside phpmyadmin. This is what I use to work with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use trigger on your specific column.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
 FOR EACH ROW
if NEW.column1 <> OLD.column1
begin 
@new_index = NEW.youColumn
--put @new_index in your desired table using UPDATE statement
end
END
```

Comment: Ok perhaps treat me like a complete idiot. Spell it out for me, WHERE do I go to do this? HOW do I make it tie to the CORRECT thing so that it doesn't update the wrong entry/entries? Can I do this in PHPMyAdmin? Can you demo an example for me using the table data I have provided, so that it makes more sense and is clear for me? At the moment it may as well be a recipe for Baklava.

Comment: Can I set this up from within a MySQL dump file (.sql) and then reimport it? If so, what would be the syntax to set it up there?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER statusUpdateTrigger AFTER UPDATE on app_AIGs2GRA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.status <> OLD.status
  THEN
    UPDATE status_index SET status = NEW.status 
      WHERE appNo = NEW.appID AND applicationKey = 'AIGs2GRA';
  END IF;
END;
```

Here's a demo in a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/768c2/1. Now you would need to create this trigger for each of the individual app tables, and specify the applicationKey in each trigger (unless its in another relation somewhere and you can grab it that way)

You can create triggers in phpMyAdmin the same way you run queries, just by executing the SQL

**NOTE:** Because the trigger contains semi-colons in the definition, you need to alter the delimiter that phpMyAdmin uses - http://phpsblog.agustinvillalba.com/create-triggers-phpmyadmin/ that page seems to show how to do that. This is why the schema in the fiddle has // to terminate some statements.